# Failed to re-package resources, Android VR game in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I just tried to make a simple vr game using google vr sdk. And after adding only one box and plane, I run program and everything works, but when I switch to andorid platform and try to build game this is what I get:
[image]

I really don't know what to do.. any help ??

Answer (score 0):

1) Find and open your SDK Manager.exe at android-sdk folder.

2) under tool, have Android SDK tools 25.1.7 and Android SDK Platfomr-tools 24 installed.

3) uninstall Android SDK Build-tools 24 and install 23.0.1 instead.

Done.

taken from: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/760989/failed-to-re-package-resources-2.html

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems that Unity uses API level 23 (Android 6) to package your solution. If you are targeting Daydream, you must compile your solution using API level 24 (Android 7) at least. Did you try to change the minimum API level from the Player settings to Android 7?